# Dash Cognito Authentication Logout

Tags: python, flask, amazon-cognito, plotly-dash, flask-dance

I have managed to use this package [here](https://github.com/fspijkerman/dash-cognito-auth) to authorize login for my users. However, I am having trouble designing a logout system.

So far, what I’ve done is code up the following method in the class defined [here](https://github.com/fspijkerman/dash-cognito-auth/blob/master/dash_cognito_auth/cognito_oauth.py). It essentially calls the revoke endpoint documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/revocation-endpoint.html). The revoke endpoint returns a 200 response.

```
def logout_request(self):
    if self.is_authorized():
        client_id = self.cognito_bp.client_id
        client_secret = self.cognito_bp.client_secret
        
        token = session.get("cognito_oauth_token")["refresh_token"]

        resp = cognito.post(
            "/oauth2/revoke",
            params={"token": token},
            headers={"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
            auth=HTTPBasicAuth(client_id, client_secret)
            )
        assert resp.ok, resp.text

        del self.cognito_bp.token

        session.clear()

        return render_template("logout.html")

    else:
        return self.login_request()
```

Then, in the application.py folder, I have a Flask route defined:

```
@application.route("/logout", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def logout_user():
      return auth.logout_request()
```

However, for some reason, the system still keeps me logged in. I feel like I need to delete a cookie server side. Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Jumping ahead, how would I be able to design a multi page concept given that I have written an explicit server route for the “logout” endpoint?